# "ERROR creating stencil attachment" in SkiaSharp with OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, .net-core, opentk, skiasharp

I tried to get SkiaSharp to work with an OpenGL backend in a Windows App, so I found this example on the internet https://gist.github.com/d-kr/eeced4157bf926accc9c6ad435d37a37.

### The problem

On my laptop running a GTX1050 everything works fine, but on my Desktop running a GTX1060 it doesn't. Both systems run Windows. As You can see in the image below an OpenTK GameWindow is created and filled.

[image]

On my laptop you can see circles being drawn, but on my desktop it throws an error message saying `ERROR creating stencil attachment. Draw skipped`. I was able to track down the error to `OnRenderFrame()`, occurring when `canvas.DrawCircle()` is called.

### First attempt

I know SkiaSharp quite well but I'm quite new to OpenTK. **What am I missing here?** On Google I only found this post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skia-discuss/m53JH2scDh4 which suggests that this is some kind of **setup or hardware problem. So where do I start debugging this?** 
These are my dependencies:

[image]

**Thanks in advance!**

---

### Necessary code

```
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Input;
using SkiaSharp;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

// https://gist.github.com/d-kr/eeced4157bf926accc9c6ad435d37a37

namespace NetCoreDesktop
{
    public sealed class MainWindow : GameWindow
    {


    private GRContext context;
    private GRBackendRenderTargetDesc renderTarget;

    public MainWindow()
        : base(1280, // initial width
        720, // initial height
        GraphicsMode.Default,
        "window",  // initial title
        GameWindowFlags.Default,
        DisplayDevice.Default,
        1, // OpenGL major version
        0, // OpenGL minor version
        GraphicsContextFlags.ForwardCompatible) {
            Title += ": OpenGL Version: " + GL.GetString(StringName.Version);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        var glInterface = GRGlInterface.CreateNativeGlInterface();
        Debug.Assert(glInterface.Validate());
        this.context = GRContext.Create(GRBackend.OpenGL, glInterface);
        Debug.Assert(this.context.Handle != IntPtr.Zero);
        this.renderTarget = CreateRenderTarget();
        CursorVisible = true;
    }

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnUnload(e);
        this.context?.Dispose();
        this.context = null;
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
    }


    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e) {
        HandleKeyboard();
    }
    private void HandleKeyboard() {
        var keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Key.Escape)) {
            Exit();
        }
    }

    public static GRBackendRenderTargetDesc CreateRenderTarget() {
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.FramebufferBinding, out int framebuffer);
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.StencilBits, out int stencil);
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Samples, out int samples);
        int bufferWidth = 0;
        int bufferHeight = 0;
        GL.GetRenderbufferParameter(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, RenderbufferParameterName.RenderbufferWidth, out bufferWidth);
        GL.GetRenderbufferParameter(RenderbufferTarget.Renderbuffer, RenderbufferParameterName.RenderbufferHeight, out bufferHeight);

        return new GRBackendRenderTargetDesc {
            Width = bufferWidth,
            Height = bufferHeight,
            Config = GRPixelConfig.Bgra8888, // Question: Is this the right format and how to do it platform independent?
            Origin = GRSurfaceOrigin.TopLeft,
            SampleCount = samples,
            StencilBits = stencil,
            RenderTargetHandle = (IntPtr)framebuffer,
        };
    }


    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e) {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        Title = $"(Vsync: {VSync}) FPS: {1f / e.Time:0}";

        Color4 backColor;
        backColor.A = 1.0f;
        backColor.R = 0.1f;
        backColor.G = 0.1f;
        backColor.B = 0.3f;
        GL.ClearColor(backColor);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        this.renderTarget.Width = this.Width;
        this.renderTarget.Height = this.Height;

        using (var surface = SKSurface.Create(this.context, this.renderTarget)) {
            Debug.Assert(surface != null);
            Debug.Assert(surface.Handle != IntPtr.Zero);

            var canvas = surface.Canvas;

            canvas.Flush();

            var info = this.renderTarget;

            //canvas.Clear(SKColors.Beige);

            using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint {
                Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
                Color = SKColors.Red,
                StrokeWidth = 25
            }) {
                canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);
                paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
                paint.Color = SKColors.Blue;
                canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);
            }

            canvas.Flush();
        }
        this.context.Flush();
        SwapBuffers();
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, StencilBits is set to zero, which is not valid. Setting it to a fixed value (like 1) helps.

```
public static GRBackendRenderTargetDesc CreateRenderTarget() {
    ...
    return new GRBackendRenderTargetDesc {
        ...
        StencilBits = 1,
        ...
    };
}
```